# Record sorting in RethinkDB when using between()

Tags: rethinkdb

If I filter records in a query using RethinkDB's [between()](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/between/) operator on the primary key/index, do I need to explicitly sort the resulting record set by primary key, or is the resulting record set guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly order it.  (This is because the data is sharded, so which means it's faster to return it in an unspecified order, so that's the default if you don't request an ordering.)